# Hadoop / EMR tasks Outputing Data and keep total count

Tags: hadoop, amazon-emr

After completing a task using Amazon Elastic MapReduce is it typical that all key results will be written to different files ? Say I have 20k Lines of data records , but only 3 Keys . I end up with 6 files, 3 empty , 3 containing the keys and their corresponding data. I'm running 1 Master and 2 Core if that makes a difference .

I also have a second question that I haven't looked into yet, but maybe could get a quick answer. What's the best way or what ways can I keep a total count variable between all keys ? I'd like to perform an operation on the data using the total # of MR jobs. Right now my code keeps track of the count of each key

Add: When I only use 1 master , I get a _SUCCESS File and 3 part-r files. 1 contains 2 keys , 1 blank , 1 has 1 key. Do I have any control over this?

Answer (score 1):

As part of program arguments you can pass -Dmapreduce.job.reduces to control number of files. By default EMR uses reducers equal to number of nodes in the cluster.

Regarding second question, do you want to get total number of records with each key? Can you cite an example?

Comment: Lets say I have Key1 - 1000 records , Key2 - 2000 records , Key3 2000 records. Done with reduce @ this pt. Is it possible for me to know in 1 Map/Reduce Phase that I have 5000 total keys so that i could say key1 = 20% of total ?

Comment: You cannot do it using typical map reduce APIs. You might have to create 2 jobs to do so. One for getting count per key and second one to compute the percentages.